# why is my iterator implementation very inefficient?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I wrote the following python script to count the number of occurrences of a character *(a)* in the first *n* characters of an infinite string.

```
from itertools import cycle
def count_a(str_, n):
    count = 0
    str_ = cycle(str_)
    for i in range(n):
        if next(str_) == 'a':
            count += 1
    return count
```

My understanding of iterators is that they are supposed to be efficient, but this approach is super slow for very large *n*. Why is this so?

Comment: If this is Python 2, `range(n)` has to build a very large list in memory as well.

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is exactly? Is the input string infinite in the sense that `cycle` is used or is it read from a stream or something else?

Comment: That said, if you are going to use `itertools`, use it as much as possible. `return sum(1 for a in filter(lambda x: x == 'a', islice(cycle(str_), n)))`.

Comment: But a now-deleted comment still stands: this approach is a *memory*-efficient, not necessarily the fastest, way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cycle` iterator might not be as efficient as you think, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) says

> Make an iterator returning elements from the iterable and saving a
>   copy of each.
>
> When the iterable is exhausted, return elements from the saved copy. 
>   Repeats indefinitely
>
> ...Note, this member of the toolkit may require significant auxiliary
>   storage (depending on the length of the iterable).

Why not simplify and just not use the iterator at all? It adds unnecessary overhead and gives you no benefit. You can easily count the occurrences with a simple `str_[:n].count('a')`

Answer (score 0):

The first problem here is that despite using itertools, you're still doing explicit python-level for loop. To gain the C level speed boost when using itertools you want to keep all the iteration in the high speed itertools.

So let's do this step by step, first we want to get the number of characters in a finite string. To do this, you can use the itertools.islice method to get the first n characters in the string:

```
str_first_n_chars = islice(cycle(str_), n)
```

You next want to count the number of occurrences of the letter (a), to do this you can do some variation of either of these (you may want to experiment which variants is faster):

```
count_a = sum(1 for c in str_first_n_chars if c == 'a')
count_a = len(tuple(filter('a'.__eq__, str_first_n_chars))
```

This is all and well, but this is still slow for really large `n` because you need to iterate through `str_` many, many times for really large `n`, like for example `n = 10**10000`. In other words, this algorithm is `O(n)`.

---

There's one last improvement we could made. Notice how that the number of (a) in the `str_` never really change in each iteration. Rather than iterating through `str_` multiple times for large `n`, we can do a little bit of smarter with a bit of math so that we only need to iterate through `str_` twice. First we count the number of (a) in a single stretch of `str_`:

```
count_a_single = str_.count('a')
```

Then we find out how many times we would have to iterate through  `str_` to get length `n` by using divmod function:

```
iter_count, remainder = divmod(n, len(str_))
```

then we can just multiply iter_count with count_a_single and add the number of (a) in the remaining length. We don't need cycle or islice and such here because `remainder < len(str_)`

```
count_a = iter_count * count_a_single + str_[:remainder].count('a')
```

With this method, the runtime performance of the algorithm grows only on the length of a single cycle of str_ rather than `n`. In other words, this algorithm is `O(len(str_))`.